# Which hooks is this? add_action('wp',

Tags: hooks

I have seen it here: [`wp_schedule_event`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)

Code snippet:

```
 add_action( 'wp', 'prefix_setup_schedule' );
```

I couldn't find this hook anywhere in documentation, how does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hook is described on [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) in [Action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) section.